# how to receive typing indicator from user in facebook messenger

Tags: python, facebook, chatbot, messenger

I'm trying to build a chatbot in FB messenger.

I could SEND typing indicator with sender action API.

However, I can't find information about receiving it.

Is there any way to do that or is it unavailable??

Thank you!

Comment: i don´t think it´s possible. after all, you would have to send a lot of requests to your messenger callback. and it´s a visible thing, it does not make much sense to detect it in the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there is no way to detect the indicator programmatically.